# Why are some R packages (say "Repitools") unavailable for version 3.2.0?

Tags: r

I am installing some packages (such as `Repitools` and `WCGNA`) in R version 3.2.0 in Ubuntu but unfortunately I keep getting error:

> package ‘Repitools’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)

Before installing these packages I updated the old packages with command `update.packages()`.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Just tried `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("Repitools")` no errors. R version 3.2.

Comment: `Repitools` is a [BioConductor package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Repitools.html).

Comment: Should have first made sure there were copies of the old packages in the /library/ for 3.2.0 and then used `update.packages(checkBuilt-TRUE)`. (Of course it's not going to cure problems when you do not know where the packages actually are.)

Comment: @BondedDust There is a typo in your commend.

Comment: Yeah. But now it's immutable. Moral: Check all spellings in the help pages..